# applay style in all element except special element

Tags: jquery, css

HTML

```
<ul id="tree">
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" /> Level 1 - 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" /> Level 1 - 2</label>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" /> Level 2 - 1</label>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" /> Level 3 - 1</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" /> Level 3 - 2</label>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" /> Level 4 - 1</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" /> Level 1 - 3</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" /> Level 1 - 4</label>
        </li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
* :not(#tree){padding:0px}
```

i want set padding zero fro all element except `#tree` but this code `* :not(#tree){padding:0px}` set padding zero for li,lable,input?

how can except child element of #tree from padding zero?

[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kdj4zv6/)
 and i want look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8gmec9p0/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fed3sg8m/3/ ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6kdj4zv6/3/ ?

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/6kdj4zv6/5/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
:not(#tree)
{
    padding:0px;
}
```

This code means that set `padding: 0px` for all the elements but not the elements present in #tree

Also, visit this page to have a better understanding of how `:not` command works

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp